# How can I generate random numbers and store them in a random amount of re-callable variables?

Tags: python, random, numbers, minimum

So, I am trying to write a program that outputs (prints) a random number between (x = 1-1000) a random amount of times between (n = 1-10) and stores those numbers in the same random number (n) of re-callable variables. That way I can output(print) the smallest number (min) of the (x) random numbers. Here's my code so far:

```
from random import randint

for x in range (10):
    x = randint (1,1000)

for n in range (10):
    n = randint (1,10)

while n > 0:
    print(x)
    num(n) = x    
    for x in range (10):
        x = randint (1,1000)

    n = n - 1

def num_low():
    min[num(n)]

print('lowest number is', num_low())
```

As you can see, I am trying to put them into a variable by the name num(n) where (n) is the randomly generated (1-10) number so that you end up with num 1, num 2, num 3,.....num (n) etc. That way you have all the required variables and as the while loop continues it should change the name of the variable to a different name automatically. Then once they are all stored I can recall them for a min check and output the minimum variable.

Comment: IIUC, you can do this by storing your values in a dictionary

Comment: You can't create dynamically named variables. I suggest putting the random numbers in a list.

Comment: This is an XY problem. you do not want to create a random number of variables to lookup. You want to store all the random numbers that you generated. This can be done using a `list`. If you only need to keep track of the minimum you really just need one other variable to store the current minimum.

Comment: @FamousJameous In python you can create global dynamically named variables. Not guaranteed to work with locals though... (in python2 locals can be make to work too).

Comment: You can store them in a list e.g. `l = sample(range(1,1000),4)` and then apply built-in functions like min, max etc... in the list.

Comment: Please work through a tutorial on basic data agglomerations in Python.  This would include at least lists, tuples, and dictionaries.  This will give you the tools to design better applications the way you want them to work.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've just started learning python and am slowly getting the hang of it. I've never used list before, but I will look into them! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamicaly named variables are *never are good idea*. Use a `dict` or a `list` to store related values together. The n<sup>th</sup> element is then obtained by index.

```
from random import randint

nums = [randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(10)]

print('list:', nums)
print('first element:', nums[0])
print('smallest element:', min(nums))
```

### Output

```
list: [846, 240, 134, 21, 172, 624, 694, 815, 612, 656]
first element: 846
smallest element: 21
```